# Can you change the partition type on a linux server without starting up fdisk?

Tags: linux, software-raid, fdisk

I'm looking for a way to change a partition type on a linux system without starting fdisk. (In this particular case from "linux" to "softwareRAID")

The ultimate goal here is a script that is going to take /dev/sda and automatically create a software RAID1 with /dev/sdb

I'm not looking for anyone here to write me a script, just trying to provide some info changing the partition type in a script.  I can take care of the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: err, so who do i give this to!?  Thank you both for the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

or you could use sfdisk, it's also designed to be scriptable.

e.g. to change partition 1 of /dev/sda to type 0xfd (linux raid):

```
sfdisk --id /dev/sda 1 fd
```

you can also dump out an existing partition table to a file (in a format that is intended to be re-imported back into sfdisk), then modify that file with vi/awk/sed/perl/ed/whatever and then feed it back in to sfdisk.

e.g.

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sed -e 's/Id=83/Id=fd/' > /tmp/sda.txt
sfdisk /dev/sda </tmp/sda.txt
```

i often use that when building raid arrays of identical disks.  manually create the partition table on one drive then use sfdisk to copy it to the other drives.

Comment: Note that: "sfdisk: --id is deprecated in favour of --part-type", which use is: --part-type device partition-number [type]

Answer (score 5):

I would look into parted, it is easily scriptable

Comment: I think we have to call it a tie ;-)

Comment: There are some good examples of parted within Debian FAI's 'setup_storage' script.

Answer (score 1):

Use parted.  You can script it, and it won't make you reboot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to clone a partition table, `dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb; partprobe /dev/sdb` is the easiest way.